# I'd like to use point's position to make curve

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I made up nodes like this.

[image]

as a result, object was made by this node

[image]

but I get in trouble.
I join empty controler' position to curve line's start.
however, I couldn't join created random point's positions to curve line's end.

I'd like to make a result like this gif

[image]

How can I use created random point's positions that can join curve line's end.

Comment: Hi Jae, if Hulifiers answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of his answer. Thank you. By this way other people who have the same question as you will know that his answer works and is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Geometry Nodes:

[image: Geometry Nodes]

What this does is instantiate a curve line on every point and then set the position of the first point of every line to the empty's position.

Since a curve line has 2 points, every even index of a point in the realized curves is the start of a curve line.

Comment: thanks! I can complete